# In a spec, how can I assign an object to an attribute defined by attr_accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

invoice.rb:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_obj
  attr_accessor :user_obj

  after_create :create_activity
  def create_activity
    log =  "<b> Invoice created. </b>" + '<br/>' + '<span class="meta"> ' + self.user_obj.name  + ' on ' + Time.now.to_date.strftime('%d-%m') + "</span>"
    @activity = ActivityLog.new(:invoice_id => self.id,:user_id => self.user_obj.id, :log => log)
    @activity.save
  end 

end
```

invoice_spec.rb:

```
it "some case for create invoice" do
  @obj = create(:invoice)      # invoice data defined in factory file.
end
```

Error after running spec:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
# ./app/models/invoice.rb:869:in `create_activity'
# ./spec/models/invoice_spec.rb:246:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Above is my model invoice.rb which contains one attribute_accessor "user_obj" and contains information about user, I used it in "create_activity" method as "self.user_obj.name" or "self.user_obj.id".

My problem is that when I run my spec for creating an invoice, it throws an error for "user_obj" not defined. So can anyone help me to resolve it?

Comment: I don't see any code that sets `#user_obj`. If it's in your factory, add it to the question.

Comment: while creating new data i set it as params[:invoice][:user_obj] = current_user in my controller method. So my question is how to do this setup in rspec model test, so i can get user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

factory_girl can assign objects to attributes defined by `attr_accessor` just as easily as it can to attributes defined by your schema.

Just write a `:user_obj` factory, and, in your spec, use the factory to create a `UserObj` and add it to the `Invoice`:

```
it "some case for create invoice" do
  @obj = create :invoice, user_obj: create(:user_obj)
end
```

If you want every `Invoice` to have a `UserObj`, give the `Invoice` factory an association:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    user_obj
    # invoice attributes ...
  end
end
```

(That's the simplest syntax, which works when the ActiveRecord association and factory_girl factory have the same name. More on available syntax here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)

Then you can just say `create :invoice` and the `Invoice` will have a `UserObj`.

Side note: it would be nice to just call `user_obj` `user`, or some other name that says why it's not just a user. Everything in Ruby is an object ...